# What is the optimal configuration of a docker container which I need to run a tendermint node and connect to abci app?

Tags: dockerfile, tendermint

I want to write a dockerfile for running a Tendermint Node that connects to my kvstore applicaiton.

Actually I want to run Tendermint Node in the container and kvstore app on local system. But my kvstore app does not recognise any new connection.

I have seen certain Dockerfile examples mentioned in Tendermint Repository. [Tendermint Dockerfiles](https://github.com/tendermint/tendermint/tree/main/DOCKER)

But I am still not able to run a container that connects to the default kvstore application running using the abci cli on my local system.